# Spring Data Mongodb support for embedded document sorting

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Does Spring Data Mongodb support sorting the elements inside an embedded document ?

I have referred the below spring documentation, but could not find any **spring data examples for sorting the elements inside an embedded document**.

http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation

For example, in the below 'Fares' JSON object, I wanted to sort "toAirports" based on the "fare":

```
Fares {
    "_id" : ObjectId("12398c367f35f01c83d1"),
    "fromAirport" : LHR,
    "toAirports" : [
            {
                "destination" : SYD,
                "fare" : 600
            },
            {
                "destination" : JFK,
                "fare" : 350
            },
            {
                "destination" : BOM,
                "fare" : 420
            },
            {
                "destination" : SIN,
                "fare" : 380
            }           
    ]
}
```

Could you please help me with a 'Spring Data MongoDB' example to achieve the above requirement ? 
I tried to google, but could not find any helpful links.

Comment: do you mean sorting all the fields of a document so that they are displayed (example) alphabetically ? Or sorting an array in a document ? Please post an example pre and post-sorted.

Comment: I have added a sample document above to clarify your question, please help.